# View closes when trying to update ProgressView from model

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUi view that on appear, I update the progress to 90% by calling a method on the model as shown below

```
struct InstallFirmwareView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: OTAViewModel
    @State private var bodyText: String = ""
    @State private var titleText: String = "Validating"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Spacer()
            Text(titleText)
            Spacer()
            ProgressView("Downloading…", value: model.progress)
            ProgressView()
            .scaleEffect(2.0, anchor: .center)
            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .black))
            Spacer()
            Text(bodyText)
        }.padding(10.0)
        .navigationTitle("Brompton")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                model.installFirmware()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
@MainActor class OTAViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var progress : Float = 0.5
    
    func installFirmware() {
        self.progress = Float(0.9)
        
    }
}
```

However when the function is executed, the view closes with no error or anything.

Comment: It's closing because when you are updating `OTAViewModel`, `InstallFirmwareView`'s parent view is refreshing its content. Can you share the code for the parent view?

Comment: Wow Timmy you are totally right, the model is passed from view to view, how do I stop the parent view from responding to the model changes?

Answer (score 0):

As Timmy had said, because the model was shared between the views, any update to a published value caused all the views to update.